# Counting Distinct Sums

Tags: combinatorics

We are to randomly pick a number from a bag which contains {1,3,4,10}, put it back, randomly pick another, put it back, and randomly pick a third one. What are the number of possible distinct sums?

Question: Except for writing out each possibility one by one, is there a systematic way to approach this problem?

Comment: do you consider $(a,b,c)$ different from $(c,b,a)$ ?

Comment: @Jorge No, the total is the same.

Comment: Start with 4 choose 3.  Then consider the cases where a number is repeated once, and when a number is repeated twice.

Comment: By "total" do you mean "sum"?

Comment: @lulu Yes. Changed the wording.

Comment: In that case, I think you are pretty well forced to check the cases.  Here you have $10+1+1=4+4+4$ so it's possible for different choices to get to the same sum.  Perhaps that's the only such example, in which case you can just count the possible choices and subtract one.  But you need to list all the sums which coincide in this way.

Comment: At a glance it would appear that the only troublesome situations that occur are how $1+1+10 = 4+4+4$ and $1+4+4=3+3+3$, so it should be $\binom{4}{3}+4\binom{3}{2}+4 - 2$.  It is not a particularly easy thing to generalize a method for for pen-paper approaches.  You can though easily use a computer to find it.  In this case looking at the expansion of $(x+x^3+x^4+x^{10})^3$, replacing all nonzero coefficients with $1$, and evaluating at $x=1$.

Comment: Using the generating function mentioned really is equivalent to "writing each possibility out one by one" but we delegate the task to a computer.  In doing so [we find that there are 18 possibilities](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E10)%5E3).  This matches with my earlier value of $\binom{4}{3}+4\binom{3}{2}+4-2=4+12+4-2=18$.

Comment: you can, but it's basically inefficient for duch a small set.